# Pygame is not registering Mac keyboard inputs

Tags: python, macos, pygame, keyboard

```
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        print("Pressed Space")
    else:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            print("Pressed w")

screen.blit(background, background_rect)

pygame.display.update()
```

I have a Mac and for some reason its not registering any of my keyboard inputs except for left shift. How can I fix this? (Pygame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your error is because of incorrect indentation. The event checking in the `for event in pygame.event.get()` loop needs to be inside the loop to run on all events.

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        
        # moved this in one level --->
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print("Pressed Space")
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w: # no need for an "else" then an "if"
                print("Pressed w")

    screen.blit(background, background_rect)

    pygame.display.update()
```